# Confused about how the render works in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm still fairly new to rails, but I've been trying to figure it out by building a bunch of simple projects like blogs, forums, clones over the weekend.

One of the blogs that I'm working on is a typical blog with users(devise), posts, and comments. I've been following a tutorial for this.

The thing that I've been really confuse on is setting up the comments and rendering it.

The tutorial teaches me to make a partial for comment in the comment view named _comment.html.erb and then another for form _form.html.erb . I fully understand that to call the form i just do render 'comments/form' but for the comment.html.erb i need to render @post.comments how come it's not 'comments/comment'? Why is it comments with the S?

I've tried reading up on render and plurization on rails, but most of them just talk about the model.

Comment: Well, it's Rails, Convention over configuration. I'm not familiar with Rails source, but this is how Rails works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two convention over configuration things going on here that may be causing you some confusion but are meant to save time.

Rails will automagically find the right partial if it follows naming conventions, meaning if your model is `Comment` that the view partial is located in `app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb`. That means you don't have to specify the location of the partial when calling `render`, but instead can just pass the model object directly and Rails figures out that you want it to render the partial and finds it on its own.

The reason it's `comments` plural here is that you are rendering all of the `comments` as a collection, not just a single `comment`. It's a convenience feature to allow the developer to simply tell Rails to render a collection and it will automagically know to use the corresponding partial. It's identical to typing:

```
@post.comments.each do |comment|
  render 'comments/comment`, object: comment
end
```

Note how the above code is calling `render` directly on a model object so we don't have to bother specifying the location of the partial (again, assuming you followed the convention when naming and locating things). If we named the partial something else, then we'd have to specify the location like your other examples.